# Typo in the flag summary page banner

Tags: bug, status-completed, flag-history, spelling

There is a typo in the [Disputed flags page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current?group=1&status=4) banner. The word agreement is as ag**g**reement. Extra "g" is added.

In plain text:

> When flags are reviewed by trusted members of the community and they are unable to come to an ag**g**reement on how they should be handled, those flags are "disputed".

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Typo in disputed flags page]

Comment: I wonnder if perhapps therre's an Engglish diallect that spells it that way.

Comment: Oh, come on. This is just a little typo. Don't exaggggerate.

Comment: Mrs Which? Is that you?

Comment: @Randal'Thor What?

Comment: @Arulkumar Not What, [Which](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wrinkle_in_Time#Mrs._Which) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, corrected.

But, I certainly don't remember typing that.

It must have been...

[image: g-g-g-ghosts!]